# Adding the same vector to each vector in a linearly independent set

Tags: linear-algebra

How would one prove that if vectors ${v_{1}}, {v_{2}}, {v_{3}}$ are linearly independent,  ${v_{1}}, {v_{2}}, {v_{3}} \in V$ and $w \in V$, the $Dim(L({v_{1}} + w, {v_{2}} + w, {v_{3}} + w)) \ge 2$

If w is the inverse of one of those three v vectors, then the dimension will be two, in every other case - it will be three. It seems obvious, but how do I actually prove it?

Comment: You used to use MathJax... why not for this question?

Comment: Also, consider the case where $w = (v_1 + v_2) / 2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry... Didn't use MathStackexchange for quite some time, and forgot what was the symbol used for embedding latex...... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof: call $W=\mathrm{span} (v_1 , v_2 , v_3)$ and $W'=\mathrm{span} (v_1 +w , v_2+w , v_3+w)$.

1. using double inclusion you can show that
   $$ W = \mathrm{span} (v_1 , v_2 -v_1 , v_3-v_1)$$
   Since $W$ has dimension $3$, in particular $v_1 , v_2 -v_1 , v_3-v_1$ is a basis of $W$.
2. This proves that $v_2 -v_1 , v_3-v_1$ are linearly independent.
3. Since
   $$v_2-v_1 = (v_2+w)-(v_1+w) \in W'$$ $$v_3-v_1 = (v_3+w)-(v_1+w)\in W'$$
   it follows that $W'$ has two linearly independent vectors.
4. This proves that $\dim W' \ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks! What happens if we greatly increase the number of vectors in the set? Could we use the same proof if there was $n$ linearly independent vectors in the set, $n \ge 3$, we add $w$ to each vector and check if the dimension of the span of new vectors is greater than or equal to $n-1$?

Comment: @Shocky2 Exactly the same proof works for $n$ vectors. You use $v_2-v_1, v_3-v_1, v_4-v_1, ..., v_n-v_1$: these are linearly independent.