# Axler exercise 2.C.9

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ is linearly independent in $V$ and $w \in V$. Prove that
> $$\dim \mathrm{span}(v_1 + w, \ldots, v_m + w) \geq m - 1.$$

Here is my attempt. I think this proof works, but I am trying to prove this result over a general field, which could have characteristic $2$ (even though Axler assumes $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). In many cases, the proofs that I write are invalid in such a case.

> Suppose $m = 1$. Then $v_1$ is linearly independent, so $v_1 \neq 0$. If $v_1 + w = 0$, then the dimension of their span is $0$, which is greater than or equal to $1-1 = 0$. Otherwise, it's strictly positive, and likewise larger than $0$.

> Suppose now that $m \geq 2$. Pick $v_j$ for some $j \in \{2, \ldots, m\}$. Then we have
> $$
> v_j - v_1 = (v_j + w) - (v_1 + w), 
> $$
> so $v_j - v_1 \in \mathrm{span}(v_1 + w, v_j + w) \subset \mathrm{span}(v_1 + w, \ldots, v_m + w)$.  Then we have a set of $m-1$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathrm{span}(v_1 + w, \ldots, v_m + w)$. But the size of any linearly independent set of vectors is less than or equal to the size of any spanning set and, indeed, the size of any basis, so the dimension is greater than or equal to $m-1$.

Is this correct? Am I right to break this into cases and rule out $m=1$ because my construction requires $v_1$ and $v_j \neq v_1$?

Comment: I think the only thing you need to elaborate on is why the $m-1$ vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Perhaps you can try generalizing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187218/adding-the-same-vector-to-each-vector-in-a-linearly-independent-set) for larger $m$: it's essentially what you're doing, but gives more detail as to why the $m-1$ vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Your approach is correct. Here’s also an alternate approach: Let $W$ be the one-dimensional subspace generated by $w$. Consider what happens to the set in question under the quotient map $V\to V/W$.